# How do I extract JSON string using a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am currently trying to retrieve the corresponding `dial_code` by using the `name` which I am obtaining as a variable.

The application uses a map of the world. When the user hovers over a particular country, that country is obtained using 'getRegionName'. This is then used to alter the variable `name`. How can I use the variable `name` to retrieve the `dial_code` that it relates to?

**JSON**

```
var dialCodes = [
  {"name":"China","dial_code":"+86","code":"CN"},
  {"name":"Afghanistan","dial_code":"+93","code":"AF"}
];
```

**The following code runs on mouse hover of a country**

```
var countryName = map.getRegionName(code);
label.html(name + ' (' + code.toString() +  ')<br>' + dialCodes[0][countryName].dial_code);
```

This code doesn't work correctly. The `dialCodes[0][countryName].dial_code` is the part that is causing the error, but I'm not sure how to correctly refer to the corresponding key/value pair

Comment: you can't it is an Array of object. no key-value pairs.

Comment: Can you change the array (that you mistakenly call JSON) to an object with the names as keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to support old browsers:
Loop over the entries in the array and compare to the given name:

```
var dialCode;
for(var i = 0; i < dialCodes.length; i++) {
    if(dialCodes[i].name === countryName) {
        dialCode = dialCodes[i].dial_code;
        break;
    }
}
label.html(countryName + ' (' + dialCode + ')');
```

If you browser [`support`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
dialCodes.filter(function(e) { return e.name === 'China' })[0].dial_code
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties with both methods on Safari. Would you happen to know a solution to that?

Comment: I just tried it in Safari (7.0.6), and it seems to work for me. What kind of problem to you experience?

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over it, I recommend making your object more like a dictionary, for example if you are always looking up by the code (`CN` or `AF`) you could avoid looping if you did this:

```
var dialCodes = {
    CN: { "name":"China","dial_code":"+86","code":"CN" },
    AF: {"name":"Afghanistan","dial_code":"+93","code":"AF"}    
};

var code = dialCodes.CN.dial_code;
```

Or

```
var myCode = 'CN'; // for example
var code = dialCodes[myCode].dial_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an array you can use `filter` to extract the data you need.

```
function getData(type, val) {
  return dialCodes.filter(function (el) {
    return el[type] === val;
  })[0];
}

getData('code', 'CN').dial_code; // +86
```